# how to make horizontal tabs vertical

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the current set up and i would like to make the tabs vertical instead of horizontal. any help?  thanks in advance.

```
body {
    margin:1em;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#cbcbcb;
    color:#000000;  
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-style: thin;
}

h1 {font-size: 3em; margin: 20px 0;}
#centerColumn {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 600px;
    height:1000px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999999;

}
#header {
    border-style: thin;
    background-position: center;
    margin: -1em -1em 0 -1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 15.5em;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url('karrnsmall.jpeg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: scroll;

}

ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;

}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}   
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tab_content h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
.tab_content h3 a{
    color: #254588;
}
.tab_content img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Upvoted because it's an important question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `float:left;` and `overflow:hidden;` in `ul.tabs li`.

And remove `height: 32px;` in `ul.tabs`.

Comment: Yes that makes it vertical, but it also makes it full screen width: http://jsfiddle.net/YUMwM/

Comment: You would not want to set a fixed width, that would be too inflexible and may break if you changed the text.

Comment: I can't really imagine a situation where you wouldn't want a fixed width menu, especially if it's a vertical menu?

Answer (score 0):

In `ul.tabs { }`:

- change `width: 100%;` to `float:left;`

In `ul.tabs li { }`:

- remove `float: left;`

Example code:

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7Gn3/)

Comment: This shrinks the tabs to the width of the text in the tabs.  There is extraneous CSS code in your example too, but I did not focus on that.